# Identyfying fraction for each row in new row

Tags: r

```
p <- c("p1","p2","p3","p4")
a <- c(0,1,1,1)
b <- c(1,0,1,1)
c <- c(1,0,1,1)
d <- c(1,1,0,1)
x <- data.frame(p,a,b,c,d)

y <- c("p1", "p3", "p4")
```

So, I want to select on the basis of Y vector and search it from X dataframe.
Then needs to identify its fraction of total number of 1 devided by total number, in new row and then it should continue through out the rows.
Eg. On the basis of Y in the X dataframe it will make for 3 (p1,p3,p4) dataframe. Then it should calculate for all the 1 in each row like in "a" column it will be 2/4. for column "b" it will be 3/4.

Kindly let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean something like `colSums(x[x$p %in% y,-1])/nrow(x)`?

Comment: Thank you for reply, ya same like this, but the results should be reflected as new rows or after transposing as new columns. also can we change this fraction as percentage too. is their any way.

Comment: great, I got it to add in the new row or column as x$ newcol <- colSums(x[x$p %in% y,-1])/nrow(x)

Comment: Ok. So your data frame is always symmetric right?

Comment: Ya I got it thank you.